# How to remove a jquery UI element without removing elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Say I have some html that looks like thsi:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

If I then type

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
```

In console, it transforms it into a sortable. (jquery required)
Now, If I want to reset it back to the original html, How can I do that? If I type:

```
$("#sortable").remove()
```

It removes all the html.

Is there a method that removes whatever `.sortable()` creates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`destroy`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-destroy) method.

```
$("#sortable").sortable("destroy");
```

From the documentation:

> Removes the sortable functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.